# bayesian probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

**Question:**
You are currently quarantining in a house with 2 other people. All three of you decide to try and experimental vaccine, that is either effective(70% chance of preventing transmission) or ineffective(30% chance). A fourth friend who is infectious comes to stay with you. if all three of you subsequently become infected, what is the probability the vaccine is ineffective?

A. 70%
B: 92.7%
C: 86.4%
D: 89.8%

**Opinion**: I found this question quite disburbing because even though this is meant as bayesian probability question, the events are definitely not clear enough.

If I write what the question wants as the conditional probility, it would be:

```
P(vaccine is ineffective|all three people are tested positive)
```

I don't know how to apply the law of total probability when solving this one, because I'm quite confused about the logical expression of the probability.

The only possibility that I understand would be,

```
P(all 3 people infected|vaccine is ineffective)
```

-> which means with 0.3 chance that the antibody didn't form, there the conditional probability that 3 people got infected given none of them formed an antibody, should be $1^3$.

```
P(vaccine is ineffective)
```

-> since we are talking about 3 people, we should get $0.3^3$

```
P(all 3 people infected|vaccine is effective)
```

-> This one gets me so confused. I interpreted as, although the antibody had formed for all 3 people, the vaccine turned out to be ineffective(which means $0.3^3$)

```
P(vaccine is effective)
```

-> if we follow the above expression, than it would be $0.7^3$

So by calculation, the probability should be $0.027/(0.027+(0.027 * 0.343)) = 0.7446$

but this is not in the options.

Could anyone give a different interpretation of this question, and possibly come up with the proper solution for this?

Comment: It seems like you are missing two pieces of data: the unconditional probabilities of infection and vaccine effectiveness. Can we assume that the probability of infection is the same as the probability of infection given an ineffective vaccine?

Comment: The problem does not state prior vaccine (in)effectiveness: P(vaccine is ineffective). I tried to put 50-50, but it won't give any of your answers either. Are you sure you are not missing anything?

Comment: @JohnDouma That is what I thought. I assumed the probability of infection is the same as probability of infection given an ineffective vaccine, which would be 0.3.

Comment: @Momo I copied the question exactly. I also thought the question lacks clarity, because there are some missing information which I think are needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I made a mistake with my calculation. It is indeed noninformative prior (50-50). I added a full answer for your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem makes the implicit assumption that the prior probability of effectiveness is $50\%$ (the so-called uniform noninformative prior):

$$P(\text{effective})=P(\text{ineffective})=0.5$$

Then with Bayes:

$$P(\text{ineffective }|\ 3 \text{ infected})=\\\frac{P(3 \text{ infected }| \text{ ineffective})P(\text{ineffective})}{P(3 \text{ infected }| \text{ ineffective})P(\text{ineffective})+P(3 \text{ infected }| \text{ effective})P(\text{effective})} = \frac{0.7^3\cdot 0.5}{0.7^3\cdot 0.5+0.3^3\cdot 0.5}\approx92.7\%$$

So the answer is B.

Comment: Could you explain why you calculated P(3 infected|ineffective) as 0.7? That sounds quite counterintuitive from the question for me.

Comment: The problem states that ineffective vaccine has 30% chance to prevent transmission, so the probability of transmission is 0.7. Assuming independence, the probability of all three people get infected is $0.7^3$